# Rails: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, resque

I'm working on rails module in which I need to work with large amount of data(i.e 25000+), which update on pre-define frequency.

I created resque worker in which it used `Parallel` Gem to thing happens parallel and also used `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true)` transaction block in which parallel process will run.

But after executing around 20K records it throw below error:

```
Error in perform: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly 
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally 
    before or while processing the request. 
ROLLBACK
```

Environment details: **Rails 5, postgres DB**

Anyone have any suggestion, what kinda changes help me out from this error.

Comment: Any idea how to use batch processing along with above structure like Transaction block and Parallel Gem ?